# I get Bad Request error for adding form-data as Jmeter body

Tags: jmeter, form-data

I'm not sure how to add what the API Documentation says (see screenshot below) in the JMETER body:

[image]

I tried doing the following:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

However, I get the following error:

[image]

Please does anyone have a solution?

Answer (score 0):

1. Shouldn't the `taxpayer` be a single object (i.e. a [JSON Object](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_objects.asp)) rather than separate parameters?
2. Your [HTTP Header Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager) doesn't make any sense, if you tick `Use multipart/form-data` box JMeter automatically sets the relevant [Content-Type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type) header
3. If you're able to successfully execute the request in browser via `Try it out` button you can just [record the file upload request](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/recording-file-uploads-jmeter) using JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html), just make sure to copy the file to JMeter's "bin" folder before "trying it out"